# How to write a custom 'attempt' parser in FParsec?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec, error-recovery

I'm trying to write a **custom `attempt` parser** in FParsec. I tried it, but I'm an F# / FParsec beginner and get lost with the F# compiler errors I produce. This is my best guess so far:

```
let customAttempt (p: CharStream<State> -> ParserResult<SyntaxNode,State>) : Parser<SyntaxNode,State> =
    fun (stream: CharStream<State>) ->
        let previousState = stream.State
        let (result, diagnostics) = p stream //This causes Error FS0001 This expression was expected to have type ''a * 'b' but here has type 'ParserResult<SyntaxNode,State>'  
        match diagnostics with
        | [] -> result 
        | _ -> 
            stream.BacktrackTo previousState
            result //Here I actually want to return a result associated with previousState
```

**Why would I ever need to write a custom attempt parser?**

Because I want to attempt parsers that never fail. In [the FParsec attempt documentation](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.attempt), they say

> The parser `attempt p` applies the parser `p`. If `p` fails after changing the parser state or with a fatal error, `attempt p` will backtrack to the original parser state and report a non‐fatal error.

In my case, the parser `p` *never* fails. What I'm currently implementing is an error recovery for my parser based on the approach described in [this block post](https://willspeak.me/2020/09/10/error-recovery-in-fparsec.html). This approach is to construct a parser `p` that never fails. Instead, it would always return a `Parser<SyntaxNode,State>` value, where `SyntaxNode` is a type for an optional parser result, and `State` is a list of `Diagnostics`. In case this list is empty, the parser `p` was successful.

The mentioned approach to error recovery in FParsec works well for simple grammars. My grammar is more complex and involves `choice`, `attempt`, or `skipManyTill` parsers. Since `p` never fails in my case, these original FParsec parses do not do the trick anymore.

Therefore, I'm trying to write my own versions of `customChoice`, `customAttempt`, or `customSkipManyTill`, so that I can use them for my grammar that would also support error recovery based on the mentioned approach of parsers that never fail but emit diagnostics instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting idea. I'd be curious to know how it turns out.

I think the problem with your code is that you're assuming that a parser returns a `(result, diagnostics)` tuple, but this is not correct. Diagnostics are actually stored in the stream state, not returned by the parser. I think you want to check the return value of the parser to determine whether to backtrack, so the code should probably look something like this:

```ml
let customAttempt (p : Parser<SyntaxNode, _>) =
    fun (stream : CharStream<_>) ->
        let state = stream.State
        let reply = p stream
        if reply.Result = SyntaxNode.Error then
            stream.BacktrackTo(state)
        reply
```

Note that I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it works. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It solved my f# compiler problem but not my core problem. I need some more investigation into this to follow up.